# Buzzer symbol in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

I miss the symbol for a buzzer in circuitikz. The labeling and orientation for the buzzer should work like the "push button". The "legs" in the symbol should be part of the symbol. So no additional line need to be draw. Using the symbol as im my example. An option for scaling the buzzer would certainly make sense.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (p0) to[vsource, name=vsource]
         (0,2) coordinate (p1) --
       ++(1,0) coordinate (p2) --
       ++(0,1) coordinate (p3) to[push button, l_=$T_1$]
       ++(2,0) coordinate (p4) --
       ++(0,-1) coordinate (p7);
  \draw (p2) --
       ++(0,-1) coordinate (p5) to[push button, l^=$T_2$]
       ++(2,0) coordinate (p6) --
       (p7) to[buzzer, l^=$B_1$]
       ++(2,0) coordinate (p8) to[buzzer, l_=$B_2$]
       ++(0,-2) coordinate (p9) to[buzzer, l_=$B_3$]
       (p0);
  \node[inner sep=2pt, anchor=south east] at (vsource.e) {\tiny $+$};
  \node[inner sep=2pt, anchor=north east] at (vsource.w) {\tiny $-$};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Expected output:

[image]

I know that it is possible to define a new bipole in circuitikz, but my knowledge is not (yet) sufficient.

Comment: Hi! Welcome! Is there any standard defining the buzzer symbol? I have to admit that this is the first time I see it... ;-). The component in itself is quite easy to define; I'll have a look when I can (if you want, you can open an issue at https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues so that I can track it)

Comment: The symbol can be found here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Schaltzeichen_(Mess-,_Steuer-_und_Regelungstechnik)
There are two main variants: The German names are "Klingel" and "Summer". I need this time the "Klingel" variant. The ratio of the distances between the incoming lines is 1:2:1

Comment: Errata: ratio is 1:3:1

Comment: **update** https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/624

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### update

The shapes will be available in 1.5.0: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/624

#### original answer

There are a lot of symbols [on the linked page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Schaltzeichen_(Mess-,_Steuer-_und_Regelungstechnik)) --- probably they are in fields different from electronics, which is my field ;-) and the main objective of `circuitikz`. Anyway, it should not be difficult to add some of them.

This is a "quick and dirty" solution. I just copied the "`mic`" over (as explained in the chapter about new components in the manual) and then modified it.

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\makeatletter

\ctikzset{bipoles/buzzer/height/.initial=0.6}%
\ctikzset{bipoles/buzzer/depth/.initial=.1}%
\ctikzset{bipoles/buzzer/width/.initial=.4}%
%
\pgfcircdeclarebipolescaled{misc}
{}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/buzzer/depth}}
{buzzer}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/buzzer/height}}
{\ctikzvalof{bipoles/buzzer/width}}{%
    \pgfscope
        \pgf@circ@setlinewidth{bipoles}{\pgfstartlinewidth}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
        \pgfpatharc{0}{180}{\pgf@circ@res@right}
        \pgf@circ@draworfill
    \endpgfscope
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.6\pgf@circ@res@left}{.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.6\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@left}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.6\pgf@circ@res@right}{.4\pgf@circ@res@up}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.6\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\pgf@circ@res@right}{0pt}}
    \pgfusepath{draw}
}
\pgfcirc@activate@bipole@simple{l}{buzzer}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
  \draw (0,0) coordinate (p0) to[vsource, name=vsource]
         (0,2) coordinate (p1) --
       ++(1,0) coordinate (p2) --
       ++(0,1) coordinate (p3) to[push button, l_=$T_1$]
       ++(2,0) coordinate (p4) --
       ++(0,-1) coordinate (p7);
  \draw (p2) --
       ++(0,-1) coordinate (p5) to[push button, l^=$T_2$]
       ++(2,0) coordinate (p6) --
       (p7) to[buzzer, l^=$B_1$]
       ++(2,0) coordinate (p8) to[buzzer, l_=$B_2$]
       ++(0,-2) coordinate (p9) to[buzzer, l_=$B_3$]
       (p0);
  \node[inner sep=2pt, anchor=south east] at (vsource.e) {\tiny $+$};
  \node[inner sep=2pt, anchor=north east] at (vsource.w) {\tiny $-$};

\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of the new component]

Comment: Thanks for the work. There is a small problem, for example, in the lower left corner of buzzer B_1. Thick lines do not close in the corner.

Comment: Oh, yes. Just add a `\pgfpathclose` before the `\pgf@circ@draworfill`.